# Is $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ a random variable?

Tags: probability

If X and Y are random variables, is

$$\mathbb E[Y|X]$$

a random variable also? Intuitively it seems to be the case, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Yes. Definition.

Comment: Huh.   What if $X$ is the random variable that is identically equal to 0?  Then you don't even have something well defined, do yo u?

Comment: @Alan If $X$ is any constant random variable, then the sigma field generated by $X$ is the trivial sigma field. In this case, $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$, which we can still think of as a random variable, albeit constant.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is consistently confusing for people. It's a worthy question and should not be closed.

Comment: @kccu Thanks.  Stats is one of my weakest areas,  though I did take a graduate level mathematical probability class 3 years ago

Comment: $f(x) = E[Y|X=x]$, the conditional expectation, is a function defined on the range of $X$. Then $f(X)$ is a random variable, called $E[Y|X]$.

Answer (score 3):

$E[Y | X]$ is just shorthand for $E[Y|\mathcal{F}]$ where $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(X)$ is the sigma field generated by the random variable $X$. Now $E[Y|\mathcal{F}]$ is a random variable by definition. (It is a random variable $Z$ measureable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\int_A Z\ dP = \int_A Y \ dP$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$).